# Putting a drop down menu on iWeb created site using exterrnal HTML code

Tags: html, menu, drop-down-menu, iweb

I am a college student trying to create a website for my professor. Since I have no background in computer science, I opted for iWeb, and I have run into some problems.

While iWeb is sufficient for most of our purposes, we would like to integrate a drop down navigation bar that requires an external code. I found a program (Sothink DHTML) that helped me create the code for the bar, but I do not know how to insert it into iWeb (I have been editing the HTML on Dreamweaver, since it does not allow me to do it on iWeb).

So far, I have been able to insert the code at the appropriate place (by putting a tag like "menuhere" on iweb, and search for it on HTML and replace the word with my code). Every time I publish the site, however, iWeb rewrites the code and the navigation bar is gone.

Could someone please help me? Thank you SO MUCH for your help in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With iWeb, you need to publish the site to your disk, open the appropriate HTML file that it generates, and paste your HTML code where you want the navigation bar to go. A good way to know that is to put some text where you want it (i.e.: `NAVBARGOESHERE`) and look for that little bit when you add the code. Just a simple little trick, but you can't do it right from within iWeb (Apple slaps your hand like a kid going for a cookie jar).

Hope this helps!